# Does this modified notion of a limit have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, terminology

Given a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between metric spaces, define:

$$\mathop{\mathrm{clust}}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \left\{b \in Y : \forall \varepsilon>0\ \forall \delta>0\ \exists a' \in X\text{ s.t. }d_X(a',a)<\delta\text{ and }d_Y(fa',b)<\varepsilon)\right\}$$

So basically, it's like we're taking a limit, except that we can get more than one value. For instance, if we take the $\mathrm{clust}$ of a step function as $x$ approaches the argument at which the step occurs, we'll get 'both' values.

This seems to be closely related to the notion of a [cluster point of a filter in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Clustering).

> **Question.** Does what I'm denoting $\mathrm{clust}$ have an accepted name or notation, and has there been any work in the direction of doing calculus with it? For example, I'd like to know about the properties of the 'cluster derivative' $$\mathop{\mathrm{clust}}_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Comment: Interesting question. If $f$ is continuous, then $\operatorname{clust}$ is the same as the usual limit, right? (I'm lazy, I don't want to write down the proof.)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud For the limit we are not allowed to take $x = a$ though (punctured neighbourhoods) or jump discontinuities like for $\chi_{\{0\}}$ would have no limit.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't understand what you mean. Could you be clearer, please? Are you talking about the derivative?

Comment: For usual limits we want $a'$ with $0< d_X(a,a') < \delta$, or else we'd take $a' = a$ always, and $f(a)$ would always be a "cluster point" in your definition. Also, usually $a \in X'$ is assumed.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud The usual definition of limit makes an exception for $x=a$ when taking limits to $a$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, but that shouldn't be a problem. Also, the OP should specify if taking $a'=a$ is allowed if $f$ is defined at $a$.

Comment: If I don't miss something, the definition can be generalized to non-metric topological spaces:
$$\mathop{\mathrm{clust}}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \left\{b \in Y : \forall \text{ open } U \ni a, \ \forall \text{ open } V \ni b \ \exists a' \in X\text{ s.t. } a' \in U\text{ and }f(a') \in V\right\}$$

Comment: There exists a continuous nowhere-differentiable $f:\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ that is periodic with period $1,$ such that $clust_{h\to 0}[f(x+h)-f(x)/h]=\mathbb R$ for every $x\in \Bbb R.$

Comment: I think the biggest problem with the "cluster derivative" is that it does not yield a function $X\to Y$ (see the example of DanielWainfleet). You can consider it a function $X\to\mathcal P(Y)$ though. If you can define a metric on $\mathcal P(Y)$, then the second cluster derivative is a function $X\to\mathcal P(\mathcal P(Y))$ and so on.